# Obtaining Unique Line from Unix 'join'

Tags: unix, join

Given these two files

```
file1.txt
------
foo 
bar

file2.txt
------
foo 1
foo 2
bar 31
```

How can I obtain the first line of successful join in file2.txt?
The expected result after joining is:

```
foo 1 
bar 31
```

I tried this but didn't work:

```
join file1.txt file2.txt
```

What's the right join command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The join you tried will print both instances of `foo` from `file2`. If you want to pick only one, you could use `sort` to ensure there are unique entries in both files before you do the actual join:

```
join <(sort file1) <(sort -k1,1 -u file2)
```